# PDO returns an object that looks blank, how can I view more info?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

I have a connection as below:

```
$dsn        = 'mysql: host=localhost; dbname=ami';
$user       = 'root';
$password   = 'password';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    var_dump($pdo);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I use var_dump, but the output is

> object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

where `{}` looks empty.  I am clueless about whats wrong!

Comment: what are you trying to do anyway? what are you expecting to have? there is **nothing** wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an empty object. `var_dump` is showing you less information about that returned object.

In my case. this is my output with `var_dump`

```
object(PDO)[160]
```

If you want to see more detailed information. Use symfony [var_dumper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) component.

Here is it's output.

[image: PDO]